# Get namespace from xml file C#

Tags: c#, xml

I've browsed the questions with similar titles but cannot seem to find exactly what I'm looking for,if anyone spotted a similar question kindly point me to the thread.Here is my question:

I have an xsd file which starts of like this:

[image: Beginning of my xsd file]
I need to know how to programatically access the namespace value of the above file.

Additionally my solution needs to be generic so I cannot simply search for `xmlns:xs` because the exact name of the namespace may have a different name

I've tried the following, but when debugging the value of the `elementNamespace` variable is blank `""`:

```
XElement elemet = XElement.Load(@"D:\xsd\Response.xsd");
string elementNamespace = elemet.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Namespace " + elementNamespace);
```

Comment: You are missing an 'n' in element. `string elementNamespace = element.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has an article on how to get the namespaces:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link i used the LINQ to XML approach

Answer (score 6):

Thats because the default namespace is blank / not specified.  I'd **guess** that you want [`GetNamespaceOfPrefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getnamespaceofprefix.aspx):

```
string elementNamespace = elemet.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xs").NamespaceName;
```

Although that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to be honest - I'm not really sure what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up using from the [Scott Hanselman article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx)

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetXmlNamespaces(string sourcePath)
{
    XDocument y = XDocument.Load(sourcePath);
    XPathNavigator foo = y.CreateNavigator();
    foo.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element);
    return foo.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All);
}
```

Usually the namespace I want is in the value of the 2nd element of the dictionary which I access like so:

```
var namespace = GetXmlNamespaces("myfile.xml").ElementAt(1).Value;
```